# How can i override the default value of an inherited modelfield in Django?

Tags: django, inheritance, mezzanine

I have a model that inherits from Mezzanine's "Displayable" model that itself inherits from the "Slugged" model. In the Slugged model there are these lines:

```
gen_description = models.BooleanField(_("Generate description"),
        help_text=_("If checked, the description will be automatically "
                    "generated from content. Uncheck if you want to manually "
                    "set a custom description."), default=True)
```

For the model i did create i want the default behaviour to not create a description automatically. Overriding the field itself is - of course - not going to work.

My first guess was this:

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.gen_description = False
        super(CyclesMaterial,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

but no luck. I did not really expect this to work, but still gave it a try.

Trying to find a solution i found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767642/model-inheritance-and-property-default-value). So i tried to do this in my model:

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('gen_description', False)
        super(CyclesMaterial,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

but it's not working.

What to do to achieve what i want to? Is it possible?

Comment: In what way is your second solution not working? If it provides an error, can you post a traceback?

Comment: As pointed out, your second solution should be working.

Comment: It is not working in a way that gen_description is still set to True. When creating a new entry for my model via the admin interface the checkbox for gen_description is still ticked.

Comment: @marue Check the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before a model is instantiated, it's fields are an actual instance of a `Field` subclass (such as `BooleanField`). Direct assignment of a value does not work yet. Only in the Model's `__init__` method do they get replaced with their actual value.

That's why your first method doesn't work: you try to assign a value before calling `super(CyclesMaterial, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`, and override the `BooleanField` instance. The model no longer sees `gen_description` as a model field, but just as a regular object attribute.

I have just tested your second solution, and these are my results:

```
# No value set
>>> c = CyclesMaterial()
>>> c.gen_description
False
# Value set to `True`
>>> c = CyclesMaterial(gen_description=True)
>>> c.gen_description
True
# Value set to `False`
>>> c = CyclesMaterial(gen_description=False)
>>> c.gen_description
False
```

That is exactly the behavior I expect, and if I understood your question correctly, the behavior you want. If `gen_description` is not set, it won't be in `kwargs`, and `kwargs.set_default('gen_description', False)` will set it to `False`. If it is set, it will be in the `kwargs`, and it's value will be preserved and set directly on the model.

**EDIT**:

If you want the default value to change in your admin interface or in other forms, you'll have to manually override it in your forms. `ModelForm`s are generated based on the class definition, and you can't change the field's options without changing them for all superclasses as well. So you'll have to change the `initial` value for the forms, overriding the generated default:

```
# either this:
form = CyclesMaterialForm(initial={'gen_description': False})

# or this:
class CyclesMaterialForm(forms.ModelForm):
    gen_description = forms.BooleanField(_('Generate description'), 
        help_text=_("If checked, the description will be automatically "
                    "generated from content. Uncheck if you want to manually "
                    "set a custom description."), initial=False, required=False)
```

Then change all instances of your form to use either the first solution, or to be an instance of `CyclesMaterialForm` as provided in the second solution.

Comment: Thanks, i was not aware of the admin form using the models class definition, so this is completely what i needed.